# How to delay running code until overlay is loaded in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I am having an issue trying to get a progress overlay to load prior to executing some code in Swift 5.
I need to do an audio conversion prior to uploading and if the file is over 20 minutes, it takes enough time to convert where I want to present some notification to the user so I decided to implement an overlay that has an Activity indicator and dims the background.
The overlay works exactly as expected on its own but if I try to run the conversion function right after calling it, the overlay doesn't load until the conversion function is complete which make no sense.

Broken down, here is some sample code:

```
@IBAction func uploadClick(_ sender: Any) {
self.startOverlay()  
self.startAudioConversion()
```

I even tried;

```
self.startOverlay() { result in   //After adding a completion handler to the startOverlay function
   if result {
      self.startAudioConversion()
   }
```

but that makes no difference. The overlay won't load until the conversion code is complete.

Like I mentioned if I remove the startAudioConversion function call, the overlay loads as expected. I tried running the overlay in a DispatchQueue, that didn't make any change.
I'm probably missing something obvious but any suggestions would be appreciated greatly.

I can make it work by adding a 0.5s delay before calling the function in the completion handler of the UI call like so;

```
       self.startOverlay() { done in
            print("Overlay should be running...")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [self] in
            self.startAudioConversion() { acresult in
            ....//This works
```

Even though it works I have to believe there is a better way to do this.

Initially I had tried using a UIAlertController instead of an overlay but I had the exact same issue where the alert controller wouldn't load until the other code was completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code and the symptoms you describe it sounds like the code in your `startAudioConversion` method is running on the main queue. This is blocking the user interface and preventing the overlay from appearing correctly. You never want to allow longer running code to execute on the main queue.

The use of `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` made issue less obvious because it gave the overlay enough time to appear as desired but you still end up blocking the user interface. The OS could terminate your app if it discovers your main queue is not responding after a short time.

The solution is to perform the code in `startAudioConversion` on a background queue. It seems you already have a completion handler parameter to know when it's complete so it's easy to run the code on a background queue.

If you have something like this:

```
func startAudioConversion(_ completion: (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
    // Run the conversion code here
    completion(someResult)
}
```

You refactor to something like:

```
func startAudioConversion(_ completion: (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // Run the conversion code here
        completion(someResult)
    }
}
```

The calling code doesn't need to change unless the block you pass as the completion handler needs to perform any UI updates. Then your calling code needs to use `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` around the UI code.

---

Another option is to use the newer async/await features of Swift instead of using completion handlers and `DispatchQueue`. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.